# bootstrap tag input with data from mysql

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**okay, I am close to killing myself, 
I have two input fields, one can have tags, and the other one can show suggestion from myself, how do i combine these to input field?**

**the code is:**

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>




<style>


    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #111;
    }

    .content {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .tt-hint,
    .city {
        border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        font-size: 24px;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 30px;
        outline: medium none;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        width: 400px;
    }

    .tt-dropdown-menu {
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #111;
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
    }
</style>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input.city').typeahead({
            name: 'city',
            remote: 'city.php?query=%QUERY'

        });

    })
</script>
```

```
    <form>
        <h1>Try it yourself</h1>



       <input type="text" id="firstInput" value="html,hemtl2" class="city" size="50" data-role="tagsinput">  
       <!--<input type="text" id="firstInput"  size="50">   -->

        <input type="text" onchange="showHint()" id="secondInput" name="city" size="40" class="city" placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code">


    </form>
</div>
```

**I have tried anything!**

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: your title contains "mysql". If this is indeed a db-related issue, the code and appropriate tag for it should be added. Is this also "php" related?

Comment: this `value="html,hemtl2"` suggests a typo where it might have to read as `value="html,hmtl2"`

Comment: ok, someone popped an answer below; see that. I've asked for clarification here.

Answer (score 0):

1. showHint() function does not exist in your code.
2. missing semicolon at the end of the script.
3. Take a break and continue tomorrow.
   Hope that helps.cheers.